# Android Studio 2.2 Conversion='v' Build Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

Recently updated my Android Studio after not working on Android for a few months. I get this error every other time I do a build.
[image]

I haven't changed much in my project since I used to work on it and it used to build fine. The main thing I've noticed is even though I do the same to build every time before getting the error it only executes one task. Where as on a working build several tasks execute.

From looking at the internet most people get this when they change their strings however I've only made one string value change so I doubt it is that.

Any ideas what this could be?

Update: It seems like its the Android Support plugin:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: Yeah, I've even tried uninstalling and reinstalling